java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource (eclipselink 4.0.2 + GWT 2.11.0)
I am updating a ~10 years old java GWT project. I replaced old eclipselink version to eclipselink 4.0.2 (comes with jakarta). It compiles but when I start it in Eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource pops up.
I tried to google it but no luck so far, can't see the proper jar file to download, however, I feel this can be a simple problem.
This project is an Ant project, not a Maven one.
   [WARN] Failed startup of context c.g.g.d.s.j.WebAppContextWithReload@3dd666d3{/,file:///home/halacs/WORK/eclipse-workspace/myproject/war/,UNAVAILABLE}{/home/halacs/WORK/eclipse-workspace/myproject/war}
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/sql/DataSource
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceXML(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:687)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.processPersistenceArchive(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:654)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.PersistenceUnitProcessor.getPersistenceUnits(PersistenceUnitProcessor.java:540)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchive(JPAInitializer.java:185)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfoInArchives(JPAInitializer.java:167)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.deployment.JPAInitializer.findPersistenceUnitInfo(JPAInitializer.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceProvider.java:191)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:80)
    at jakarta.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
    at hu.halacs.myproject.server.filters.EntityManagerFilter.init(EntityManagerFilter.java:154)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:140)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.lambda$initialize$0(ServletHandler.java:731)
    at java.base/java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.forEachRemaining(Spliterators.java:992)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:755)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:379)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1414)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:910)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:288)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:524)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload.doStart(JettyLauncher.java:496)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:169)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:423)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:387)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:73)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher.start(JettyLauncher.java:640)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.doStartUpServer(DevMode.java:636)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.startUp(DevModeBase.java:898)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevModeBase.run(DevModeBase.java:705)
    at com.google.gwt.dev.DevMode.main(DevMode.java:432)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.sql.DataSource
    at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.jetty.JettyLauncher$WebAppContextWithReload$WebAppClassLoaderExtension.loadClass(JettyLauncher.java:422)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:525)
    ... 39 more


Check the version of java which was used to compile with the version being used a runtime. Is the runtime version old? This would explain why it doesn't have this class/interface

I have found that class in 21.0.2. Thanks!
